# SocketIO com Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação realtime com express (^4.17.1"), node (10.12.0) usando typescript.

Só que só no socket que está dando problema de cors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mo_nwPh'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Minha classe de configuração é essa aqui

```
class Aplicaccao {
    app: express.Application
    port = 3000
    private io: SocketIO.Server
    private server: Server;
    constructor(){
        this.app = express()
        this.server = createServer(this.app);
        this.io = socketIo(this.server);
    }
    listen(){

        this.middleware()
        this.realtime()
        this.routes()

        this.app.listen(this.port, ()=>{
            console.log(`System is listening on port ${this.port}`);            
        })
    }

    middleware(){
        this.enableCors()
        this.app.use( bodyParser.json() )
        this.app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {extended: true} ) )
    }
    enableCors(){
        const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
                            "origin": "*",
                            "methods": "*",
                            "preflightContinue": false,
                            "optionsSuccessStatus": 200
                        }
        this.app.use(cors(options))           
    }
    realtime(){
        this.io.on('connect', socket =>{
            console.log('socket',socket);

            socket.on('read', msg =>{
                socket.broadcast.emit('read', msg)
            })
        })
    }

    routes(){
        this.app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
            res.send({obs: 'Bem vindo a api do Sistema de Notificações'})
        })
        this.app.use('/api', ...routes)
    }
}

export const server = new Aplicaccao()
```

A chamada no angular está assim:

```
this.socket = io( 'http:localhost:3000' )
```

E no javascript assim:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
```

Como pode ser problema CORS se os outros módulos da API funcionam: Consulta, insert, update?

Onde posso estar errando?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, para dar este erro você deve estar utilizando `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials` como `TRUE` (geralmente utiliza essa propriedade como true quando precisa enviar cookie).
Para resolver seu problema você pode passar essa propriedade como `FALSE`, caso não precise enviar cookies.
Agora, se realmente precisa utilizar `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials` como `TRUE`, você deve adicionar o domínio de origem que quer permitir, e não passar `*` pois isso fica muito permissivo e da este erro.
Altere este seu pedaço de código para:

```
const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
  //Ou altere o http://localhost:3000 para o protocolo+dominio+porta de onde esta vindo as requisições.
  "origin": "http://localhost:3000", 
  "methods": "*",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 200
}
```

Comment: Bom eu mudei pro restify, e funcionou sem burocracia

Comment: @adventistaam, desculpe não ter conseguido lhe ajudar antes, mas que bom que você conseguiu!

Comment: Valeu pela tentativa...